# calculate moving average every n hours

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame, a time series with 4 observation every hour for each site.

I'd like to compute moving average for every 4 hours, using data.table, I can do it per hour but not every n hours.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1414502100, 1414503000, 1414503900, 
1414504800, 1414505700, 1414506600, 1414507500, 1414508400, 1414509300, 
1414510200, 1414511100, 1414512000, 1414512900, 1414513800, 1414514700, 
1414515600, 1414516500, 1414517400, 1414518300, 1414519200, 1414520100, 
1414521000, 1414521900, 1414522800, 1414523700, 1414524600, 1414525500, 
1414526400, 1414527300, 1414528200, 1414529100, 1414530000, 1414530900, 
1414531800, 1414532700, 1414533600, 1414534500, 1414535400, 1414536300, 
1414537200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), site = c(2108L, 
2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 
2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 
2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 
2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 2108L, 
2108L, 2108L, 2108L), val = c(38L, 38L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 37L, 
38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 33L, 31L, 27L, 26L, 20L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 
7L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), month = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
    hour = c("14", "14", "14", "15", "15", "15", "15", "16", 
    "16", "16", "16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", 
    "18", "19", "19", "19", "19", "20", "20", "20", "20", "21", 
    "21", "21", "21", "22", "22", "22", "22", "23", "23", "23", 
    "23", "00"), min = c("15", "30", "45", "00", "15", "30", 
    "45", "00", "15", "30", "45", "00", "15", "30", "45", "00", 
    "15", "30", "45", "00", "15", "30", "45", "00", "15", "30", 
    "45", "00", "15", "30", "45", "00", "15", "30", "45", "00", 
    "15", "30", "45", "00"), day = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L)), .Names = c("time", 
"site", "val", "month", "hour", "min", "day"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 191430:191469)



 dt<- data.table(df)
    dt[, ':=' ('hsd' = sd(val)), by = list(site, hour, day)]

 head(dt, 10)
                   time site val month hour min day      hsd
 1: 2014-10-28 14:15:00 2108  38    10   14  15  28 1.732051
 2: 2014-10-28 14:30:00 2108  38    10   14  30  28 1.732051
 3: 2014-10-28 14:45:00 2108  35    10   14  45  28 1.732051
 4: 2014-10-28 15:00:00 2108  35    10   15  00  28 1.000000
 5: 2014-10-28 15:15:00 2108  35    10   15  15  28 1.000000
 6: 2014-10-28 15:30:00 2108  35    10   15  30  28 1.000000
 7: 2014-10-28 15:45:00 2108  37    10   15  45  28 1.000000
```

Is this the right way to compute moving average and how can I calculate it for more than one hour

Comment: I suspect data.table doesn't have the best tools for rollers. You can use it together with RcppRoll or zoo, though. Maybe I've misunderstood... showing your desired output would help clarify.

Comment: I'm wondering what you mean by calculate every 4 hours? You want means for 4 hour intervals?

Comment: yes that is what I need

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649913/calculating-sum-of-previous-3-rows-in-r-data-table-by-grid-square/) or many similar questions. You just need to divide by some `n` in order to convert sum to a mean.

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking about moving averages but then computing a standard deviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` and `zoo`. Here I'm grouping by site even though your sample data only includes one site, because I'm guessing that your actual data includes many. I'm also assuming that you want values for overlapping intervals, not sequential ones.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

new.df <- df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%  # This only matters if your actual data have multiple sites
  mutate(moving.avg = rollmean(x = val, width = 16,  # 16 is 4 hours x 4 obs per hour
    align = "right", fill = NA))
```

If you only want the mean for sequential windows -- i.e., every four hours, or in this case every 16th observation within each group -- then use `rollapply` with the `by` and `align = "right"` options specified, i.e.:

```
mutate(moving.avg = rollapply(data = val, FUN = mean, width = 16, by = 16,
  align = "right", fill = NA))
```

Comment: This solution will compute incorrect values if some periods are missing in the data. Data has to be expanded first.