# Running Sum in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R, and I would like to apply rolling sum by group to it. But the problem is the group length is not the same and when the rollapply function reaches the shorter group, it will encounter an error. Is there a way to solve this, except for-loops?

The following is a simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
DT <- data.table(id = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 2), rep("C", 8)),
                 val = c(1:6, 1:2, 1:8))
> DT
    id val
 1:  A   1
 2:  A   2
 3:  A   3
 4:  A   4
 5:  A   5
 6:  A   6
 7:  B   1
 8:  B   2
 9:  B   1
10:  B   2
11:  B   3
12:  B   4
13:  B   5
14:  B   6
15:  C   7
16:  C   8
```

Rolling sum of 4 numbers, using `rollapplyr()`

```
DT[, cum.sum := rollapplyr(val, width = 4, FUN = sum, fill = NA), by = id]
```

But this will give me an error

```
Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

And the output is

```
> DT
    id val cum.sum
 1:  A   1      NA
 2:  A   2      NA
 3:  A   3      NA
 4:  A   4      10
 5:  A   5      14
 6:  A   6      18
 7:  B   1      NA
 8:  B   2      NA
 9:  C   1      NA
10:  C   2      NA
11:  C   3      NA
12:  C   4      NA
13:  C   5      NA
14:  C   6      NA
15:  C   7      NA
16:  C   8      NA
```

Ideally, the output should be

```
> DT
    id val cum.sum
 1:  A   1      NA
 2:  A   2      NA
 3:  A   3      NA
 4:  A   4      10
 5:  A   5      14
 6:  A   6      18
 7:  B   1      NA
 8:  B   2      NA
 9:  C   1      NA
10:  C   2      NA
11:  C   3      NA
12:  C   4      10
13:  C   5      14
14:  C   6      18
15:  C   7      22
16:  C   8      26
```

Comment: Try converting id to a factor, using `DT$id = as.factor(DT$id)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can do

```
DT[, cum.sum := Reduce(`+`, shift(val, 0:3)), by=id]

    id val cum.sum
 1:  A   1      NA
 2:  A   2      NA
 3:  A   3      NA
 4:  A   4      10
 5:  A   5      14
 6:  A   6      18
 7:  B   1      NA
 8:  B   2      NA
 9:  C   1      NA
10:  C   2      NA
11:  C   3      NA
12:  C   4      10
13:  C   5      14
14:  C   6      18
15:  C   7      22
16:  C   8      26
```

---

I knew [I'd seen this somewhere before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32650244/5977215) - possibly a duplicate?